# Complex integration issue

Tags: complex-analysis

(1) I would like to know how $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{imt}(ie^{it})\,dt = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(m+1)}dt$ holds for non-negative integer $m$. (2) I am also struggling to calculate the integral $\int_C \frac{sinz}{z^2}\,dz$ where $C(t)=2+e^{2it\pi}$ with $0\leq t\leq1$. I do have an intution that I need to use Cauchy's integral formula but it is very difficult to apply it as my book does not contain applied examples. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: (1): it is easy to calculate both integrals explicitly. As for the other sine integral, you can use Cauchy's theorem (not the integral formula). The integrand is holomorphic inside the contour of integration.

Comment: As for (1) it is difficult to see how $\int_0^{2\pi} e^{it(m+1)}idt = \int_0^{2\pi} e^{i(m+1)}dt$ holds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{imt}\left(ie^{it}\right)dt&=i\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(m+1)t}dt\\
&=\frac{i}{i(m+1)}\left[e^{i(m+1)t}\right]_{t=0}^{2\pi}\\
&=\frac{1}{m+1}\left(\cos(2(m+1)\pi)-1+i\sin(2(m+1)\pi)\right)\\
&=0
\end{align}

The last line follows from the fact that $m+1$ is a whole number and $\cos(2n\pi)$ for any whole number $n$ is always equal to $1$, whereas the $\sin(2(m+1)\pi)$ is always $0$ for any whole number $m$.

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}e^{i(m+1)t}dt&=\frac{1}{i(m+1)}\left[e^{i(m+1)t}\right]_{t=0}^{2\pi}\\
&=-\frac{i}{m+1}\left(\cos(2(m+1)\pi)-1+i\sin(2(m+1)\pi)\right)\\
&=0
\end{align}

by the same argument as for the first integral.

**Question 2**

$f(z):=\frac{\sin z}{z^2}$ is an entire function for any $z\neq0$. Your contour is a circle of radius $1$ around the point $(2,0)$ in the complex plane. Thus, no singularities of $f(z)$ are contained within $C$ and the integral evaluates to $0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, it makes sense.